# Variables inside Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

Lets say I have the code:

```
str = "foobar"
print "Enter in the letters you would like to match: "
match = gets
# Pseudocode:
str =~ /[match]/
```

I don't want to match the whole string: **match**, I just want to match each of the letters, like:

```
str =~ /[aeiou]/
```

would yield the vowels.
How do I make it so I can match the letters the user inputs?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What are you matching? Do you want to see if any chars from the user input can be found in `str`? or do you want to see if the user wrote down `str` exactly or do you want to see if the user inputs a character found in `str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
match = gets.chomp # cut off that trailing \n
str =~ /[#{match}]/
```

Comment: @MichaelKohl: no, not really. At least, that's how I understood the problem. If user inputs 'aeiou', regex becomes `/[aeiou]/`, which matches any of these vowels.

Comment: One should [Regexp.quote](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) the interpolated value, unless one intends the user input to act as regexp metachars. `str =~ /[#{Regexp.quote(match)}]/`